# $f\in L[x,y]$ such that $f(x,0)=0$ implies $f=y g$ with $g\in L[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Suppose $L$ is an infinite field (or even algebraically closed; I'm not sure if it is necessary to add that hypothesis). If we have a polynomial $f(x,y)\in L[x,y]$ and $f(x,0)\equiv 0$, does that imply $f(x,y)$ has a factor $y$ in its expression with irreducible polynomials?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any motivation for this! Somebody just asked me and I don't know if it is true.

Comment: Express as a polynomial in $y$ with coefficients being polynomials in $x$. The "constant" term is $0$ for all $x$. Since the field is infinite, this means it is the zero polynomial.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you. I see it now.

Comment: You are welcome. In my comment, I assumed that by $f(x,0)\equiv 0$ you meant that $f(x,0)$ is the identically zero **function** from $L$ to $L$. If you meant that $f(x,0)$ is the zero **polynomial**, then the answer by Nitrogen is right and requires no assumptions on the field.

Answer (score 0):

See $f=f(x,y)$ as an element of $(L[x])[y]\cong L[x,y]$, i.e., see $f$ as a polynomyal in $y$ with coefficient in $L[x]$. Then, $f(0)=f(x,0)=0$.

In any polynomial ring $R[y]$, if $f(0)=0$, then $y$ divides $f$. So that also holds in this particular case with $R=L[x]$.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Don't we need the division algorithm for your second (and hence for your first) point?

Comment: No, we dont need. We have $f=a_ny^n + \dotsb + a_1y+a_0$, hence $0=f(0)=a_0$, so we get $f=a_ny^n + \dotsb + a_1y=y(a_ny^{n-1} + \dotsb + a_1)$. The ring does not matter at all.

Comment: Though the ring does matter for the first point. To deduce that all coefficients of $f(x,0) \in L[x]$ vanish, we need $L$ to be infinite or either the equation $f(x,0)=0$ to be understood as an equality of polynomials, not of values in $L$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another proof:

Given any polynomial $f \in L[x,y]$, we can look at those monomials that admit a $y$ and those monomials, that do not. Thus we can write: $f=yg(x,y)+h(x)$.

Then use your assumption:

$$0=f(x,0)=h(x).$$

Now consider 2 cases:

1. The equation $f(x,0)=0$ is understood as an equality of polynomials. We then deduce $h=0$, hence $f=yg(x,y)$, no matter what $L$ is (it can be any ring).
2. The equation $f(x,0)=0$ is understood as an equation in $L$, that holds for any $x \in L$. Then we need $L$ to be an infinite field to deduce $h=0$ and thus $f=yg(x,y)$.